# Rearrangement of equations

Tags: functions, nonlinear-system

Trying to find solutions to the equation of $$(1/x)+1=2\sin⁡x+3$$ and I have to rearrange it into the form of $x=f(x)$ as I am using the fixed point method and iterations.

Struggling to find new arrangements and I have these rearrangements already

$$x=\sin^{-1}((1/2x)-1)$$

$$x=1/(2\sin x+2)$$

$$x=x(2\sin x)+3x-1$$

Thanks so much!

Comment: What's wrong with the arrangements you've made?  Surely they should be sufficient?

Comment: We are required to make as many rearrangements as possible and there are 5 solutions to the equation however using the ones I have made I could not find all of them. Thanks again!

Comment: Try squaring both sides and foiling, that usually gives more terms to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

If we square both sides, we get

$$\frac1{x^2}+\frac2x+1=4\sin^2(x)+12\sin(x)+9$$

And from here, we can get many forms for $x=f(x)$,

Solving for $\frac1{x^2}$:

$$\implies\frac1{x^2}=4\sin^2(x)+12\sin(x)+8-\frac2x$$

$$\implies x=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{4\sin^2(x)+12\sin(x)+8-\frac2x}}\tag{use ONLY $+$ or $-$}$$

Solving for $\frac2x$

$$\implies\frac2x=4\sin^2(x)+12\sin(x)+8-\frac1{x^2}$$

$$\implies x=\frac1{2\sin^2(x)+6\sin(x)+4-\frac1{2x^2}}$$

And you can get many more from solving on the $\sin$ side.